# Google Auth2.0 login error on ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-oauth, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a google auth2.0 for signin. I tried many way to solve, but nothings change. I think it's about nginx and .NET Core settings. I'm not using identity.  But I didn't find anything yet. My code is shown below.

Note: this error only happens in our mobile app (Android webview); the web application works normal.

`Startup.cs` (`ConfigureServices` method)

```
...
services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
{
    auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection = configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
    options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:picture", "picture", "url");
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account";
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
...
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseCustomExceptionMiddleware();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

`AccountController.cs` (when Google Login button is clicked, it calls `GoogleLogin` method)

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GoogleLogin()
{
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleResponse")
    };
    return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleResponse()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Google auth started");
    // some codes
    _logger.LogInformation("Google auth finished");
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Here is my error stack trace. I used '~~' characters for my logs

> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.GoogleHandler[15]
> => ConnectionId:0HM50OGGO9P17 => RequestPath:/signin-google RequestId:0HM50OGGO9P17:00000001, SpanId:|6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5., TraceId:6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5, ParentId:
> '.AspNetCore.Correlation.Google.wewjzQ0oDhkb63dSD.....' cookie not found.
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.GoogleHandler[4]
> => ConnectionId:0HM50OGGO9P17 => RequestPath:/signin-google RequestId:0HM50OGGO9P17:00000001, SpanId:|6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5., TraceId:6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5, ParentId:
> Error from RemoteAuthentication: Correlation failed..
> warn: WebUI.Middleware.CustomExceptionMiddleware[0]
> => ConnectionId:0HM50OGGO9P17 => RequestPath:/signin-google RequestId:0HM50OGGO9P17:00000001, SpanId:|6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5., TraceId:6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5, ParentId:
> ~~ Url for unhandled exception URL  : https://example.com/signin-google??state=XXX&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=none
> fail: WebUI.Middleware.CustomExceptionMiddleware[0]
> => ConnectionId:0HM50OGGO9P17 => RequestPath:/signin-google RequestId:0HM50OGGO9P17:00000001, SpanId:|6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5., TraceId:6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5, ParentId:
> ~~ Unhandled exception message : An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> fail: WebUI.Middleware.CustomExceptionMiddleware[0]
> => ConnectionId:0HM50OGGO9P17 => RequestPath:/signin-google RequestId:0HM50OGGO9P17:00000001, SpanId:|6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5., TraceId:6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5, ParentId:
> ~~ Unhandled exception stacktrace :
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at WebUI.Middleware.CustomExceptionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) in /home/MY_PROJECT_PATH/Middleware/CustomExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 50
>
> fail: WebUI.Middleware.CustomExceptionMiddleware[0]
> => ConnectionId:0HM50OGGO9P17 => RequestPath:/signin-google RequestId:0HM50OGGO9P17:00000001, SpanId:|6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5., TraceId:6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5, ParentId:
> ~~ Unhandled exception message : Correlation failed.
>
> fail: WebUI.Middleware.CustomExceptionMiddleware[0]
> => ConnectionId:0HM50OGGO9P17 => RequestPath:/signin-google RequestId:0HM50OGGO9P17:00000001, SpanId:|6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5., TraceId:6234ca08-46b49a3bf35855d5, ParentId:
> ~~ Unhandled exception stacktrace : (null)

*Edit:*

I noticed something. Mobile app users sign-in first(I write users' login page information to the database), but the second page needs a form post. When people submit this form (PDF upload required), it gives the above error. This error gives the mobile user, but few mobile users proceed normally

Comment: If your web app works normal, I would assume there is some difference in the way you requesting your action between web app and android app, I would start from there, not from backend

Comment: I dont think google is going to let you login via a web view they locked that down a few years ago. Your authorization needs to go though the native browser on the device.   I would look around for another error messages before this cookie one.   Your getting an error becouse the cookies not set on andorid, but why isnt the cookie being set on android, probably because its a web view.  https://auth0.com/blog/google-blocks-oauth-requests-from-embedded-browsers/

Comment: @DaImTo There is no problem when our team and our friend using. It works normal. But, if request come from different country, project gives this error